# Windows Phone 8 categorized list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, jump-list

I have a class like this:

```
class Parent
{
    string Name;
    List<Children> Items;
}
```

How do I put this into a Jump list so that it lists out the Parent.Name as the jumpable headers, but underneath it lists the Parent.Children.Items?

I have managed to get an AlphaKey to work, but that was just for the Parent.Name... now I want to utilize the Items underneath (that are already grouped by the Parent)... and display the entire Title as the jumplist headings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to group your data by using LINQ or Extension Methods into a collection. You can do this by reading the PhotoHub Sample or Contacts App Sample in MSDN.